# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'id' of 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this error message that comes in from time to time that crashes my bot.
Here is the error message in the console:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FortniteRanked8.5\events\message.js:7
  if(prefixed.hasOwn(message.guild.id)){
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FortniteRanked8.5\events\message.js:7:36)
```

The problem comes from this line:

```
if (prefixes.hasOwn(message.guild.id)){
```

Setup:

- Windows server 2012
- Discord.js : v11.4.2
- node : v8.11.1

Code:

```
const Store = require('data-store');

module.exports = (client, message) => {
  var prefixes = new Store({ path: __dirname + '/../prefixes.json' });
  // console.log(prefixes.clone())

  if (message.author.bot) return;

  var prefix = client.config.prefix

  if (prefixes.hasOwn(message.guild.id)){
    prefix = prefixes.get(message.guild.id)
  }

  if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const cmd = client.commands.get(command);

  if (!cmd) return;

  if (cmd && !message.guild)
    return message.channel.send("Vous ne pouvez pas faire de commande ici, Merci de faire les commandes directement sur votre serveur discord.");

  cmd.run(client, message, args);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`message.guild` is null, before you should check if it exists like `message && message.guild && ...`. Using this you’ll be sure that all the fields exist.

Comment: Thank you indeed I did not think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Check guild before use it

```
if(message.guild && prefixes.hasOwn(message.guild.id))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very fast answer I will do the test, I will inform you of the news

Answer (score 1):

If the error message says *"Could not read property 'id' of null"* it means that the `guild` property **exists**, but it is `null`. As it has been previously said, you have to check it, but besides that you have to check: **why** does `guild` be `null`?

In case there was no property you would get *"Could not read property 'id' of undefined"* as the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

> The `Guild` object you're accessing doesn't exist. So it has no `id` member in it. So it says, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`. Thanks to all other users contributed.
>
> More at MDN about [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError).

### The solution:

You need to check whether the guild you're accessing even exists or not. For that you need to check the guild's `available` property.

```
/* Check the evidence of guild's existance */
if(message.guild.available === true && prefixes.hasOwn(message.guild.id))
```